# How can I get list of all articles with ingredient property:?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I would like to get list of all articles containing ingredient property. I tried to figure it out on my own but the query I used did not work.

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT  *
WHERE ingredient{
 ?ingredient a dbo:ingredient.
}
```

I would appreciate if you could show me how I can get list of all articles having ingredient property and the list of the ingredients in another column.

Answer (score 1):

Your SPARQL query asks for instances of the class `dbo:ingredient`. However, if you actually visit http://dbpedia.org/ontology/ingredient, you'll see that this is a *property*, not a class.

You'll need to reformulate your query to ask for "all things that have the ingredient property", something like this:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?x
WHERE {
  ?x dbo:ingredient ?ingredient.
}
```

That will give you the resources that have an ingredient property. If you're after the actual wikipedia article link, you can further query for, for example, the value of the `foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf` property for each resource.

Generally speaking, it helps to use the DBPedia browser to get a feel for how the data is modeled: what properties are available, and which classes are used. That will inform you how to formulate your SPARQL queries.